Harmonic functions can be written as a difference of two positive harmonic functions.
$\textbf{Problem}:$ Let $u$ be any harmonic function on the unit disk $\mathbf{D}$ in the complex plane $\mathbf{C}$. $\\$
a) Prove that $|u|$ is subharmonic on the unit disk $\mathbf{D}$.
b) If there exist positive harmonic functions $u_1$, $u_2$ on $\mathbf{D}$ such that $u = u_1 - u_2$, show that $$ sup \int |u(re^{it})|\frac{dt}{2\pi} < \infty$$ where sup is taken over $r \in (0,1).$ In other words, we want to show that it is finite.
c) Conversely, if part (b) is true, then prove that there exist positive harmonic functions $u_1$, $u_2$ on $\mathbf{D}$ such that $u = u_1 - u_2$. (The converse of part (b).
$\textbf{Proof (a):}$  Since $u$ is harmonic, it satisfies Laplace’s equation:
$$\Delta u = u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0.$$
Define $ |u|(x, y) = \sqrt{u(x, y)^2} $. We seek to show that $ \Delta |u| \geq 0 $.
For $ u \neq 0 $, the function $ |u| $ is differentiable, and we have
$$
   \frac{\partial |u|}{\partial x} = \frac{u}{|u|} \cdot u_x \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{\partial |u|}{\partial y} = \frac{u}{|u|} \cdot u_y.
  $$
Applying the product rule, we get
$$
   \frac{\partial^2 |u|}{\partial x^2} = \frac{u_x^2}{|u|} + \frac{u \cdot u_{xx}}{|u|} - \frac{u \cdot u_x^2}{|u|^3},
   $$
and similarly,
$$
   \frac{\partial^2 |u|}{\partial y^2} = \frac{u_y^2}{|u|} + \frac{u \cdot u_{yy}}{|u|} - \frac{u \cdot u_y^2}{|u|^3}.
  $$
Adding these, we find
$$
   \Delta |u| = \frac{u_x^2 + u_y^2}{|u|} + \frac{u \cdot (u_{xx} + u_{yy})}{|u|} - \frac{u \cdot (u_x^2 + u_y^2)}{|u|^3}.
  $$
Since $ u $ is harmonic, $ u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0 $, so
$$
   \Delta |u| = \frac{u_x^2 + u_y^2}{|u|} - \frac{u \cdot (u_x^2 + u_y^2)}{|u|^3}.
  $$
Factoring out $ \frac{u_x^2 + u_y^2}{|u|} $, we get
$$
   \Delta |u| = \frac{u_x^2 + u_y^2}{|u|} \left( 1 - \frac{u^2}{|u|^2} \right) = \frac{|\nabla u|^2}{|u|}.
  $$
Since $ |\nabla u|^2 \geq 0 $, it follows that $ \Delta |u| \geq 0 $.
Therefore, $ |u| $ is subharmonic on $\mathbf{D}$.
$\textbf{Proof (b):}$
Since $ u_1 $ and $ u_2 $ are harmonic on the unit disk, their difference $ = u_1 - u_2 $ is also harmonic on the unit disk. Given that $ u_1 $, and $ u_2 $ are positive harmonic functions, both $ u_1 $ and $ u_2 $ satisfy the mean value property, implying that $$ \int u_1(re^{it}) \frac{dt}{2\pi} $$ and $$ \int u_2(re^{it}) \frac{dt}{2\pi} $$ are finite.
Thus,
$$
   \sup_{r \in (0,1)} \int \left| u(re^{it}) \right| \frac{dt}{2\pi} < \infty.
  $$
$\textbf{Proof of (c)}:$
Suppose $ \sup_{r \in (0,1)} \int \left| u(re^{it}) \right| \frac{dt}{2\pi} < \infty $.
Define $ f(e^{it}) = \lim_{r \to 1} u(re^{it}) $, and set $ f = f^+ - f^- $, with $ f^+, f^- \geq 0 $.
Define $ u_1 $ and $ u_2 $ using the Poisson integral:
$$
   u_1(z) = \int_{0}^{2\pi} P(z, e^{it}) f^+(e^{it}) \frac{dt}{2\pi}, \quad u_2(z) = \int_{0}^{2\pi} P(z, e^{it}) f^-(e^{it}) \frac{dt}{2\pi}.
  $$
Since $ u = u_1 - u_2 $, we conclude that $ u $ can be written as a difference of two positive harmonic functions.
$\textbf{Question}:$ I would like to ask if you can take a look at my proofs and offer some suggestions to improve it. I feel probably there is more to say in the proofs. Thank you!

For $c$ one has to be careful since the radial limit captures only the absolutely continuous part of the function on the boundary (for example if $u$ is the poisson kernel its boundary limit is zero except at $1$ where it is infinite corresponding to the singular Dirac measure at $1$ so you cannot recapture it that way

Thanks! How about part (a) and part (b)?

Can you also unravel your statement?

$a,b$ ok though $a$ can be done simpler; for $c$ the point is that taking radial limits can miss stuff as in general a harmonic function is not recoverable from its radial limit as a Poisson transform unless it is in $h^1$; as a simple example take the Poisson function itself ($u(z)=\Re \frac{1+z}{1-z}$) which is positive inside the unit disc but its radial limit is $0$ except at $1$ so its radial boundary function is $0$ ae hence its integral against any kernel is zero not $u$; this part requires looking at $du$ as a measure and its radial limit as a measure
